# Fingerprint sensor not working after updating to windows 10 1903. (Dell G3 3579)

Tags: windows-10, driver, compatibility, fingerprint, windows-hello

Goodix Fingerprint sensor not working after windows 10 1903 update on my Dell G3 3579.
It worked while installing windows 10 1903 via iso (which failed to update otherwise), windows hello was all good during setup but after first boot then it just stopped working & driver shows error code 31 on device manager.
I tried updating everything & also tried reinstalling Goodix fingerprint driver but that didn't work either. The fingerprint worked fine on the previous 1809 update of windows 10.

..

images attached showing errors.
[image]

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/Fingerprint-sensor-not-working-after-updating-to-windows-10-1903/m-p/7372782#M14435

I asked the same question at dell, they said reset. but it didn't work, and now they say you're machine has some hideous malware sitting idly in some corner of your registry or bios. I seriously doubt that, I make and reverse malwares, that is not the case, is there any serious dev- community in correlation with Microsoft & Goodix  that can actually help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update it got fixed, without re-intalling windows.

I did a couple of things with a guy from nearest dell partner who provided me free technical support at their center, He guided me a little and I did a few things on my own. I don't know what fixed it but I'll go on chronologically.

First I downloaded a utility named UsbSafelyRemove and using this I stopped the power to the fingerprint sensor virtually without having to disconnect it, this removed it from devicemanager by preventing it from getting detected for current session. Then I uninstalled the sensor driver software and it was no longer detected aswell. Then I downgraded the bios using Dells Bios Tool, Meanwhile Microsoft or maybe Dell launched an un-logged/unscheduled automatic update and perhaps a possible patch for windows, I don't know if they did it or if it was windows on its own because it wasn't logged. I then restarted the computer, the sensor was detected and appropriate drivers were automatically installed, didn't check for error at this time. Then my antivirus software also found a simple PUP.Optional.OpenCandy malware, which shouldn't likely have any effect. I enabled Microphone for a skype call and just out of the blue the sensor error code 31 which I was checking for frequently, just disappeared. I have now upgraded my bios and the sensor still appears to work. I believe the miracle was due to the windows update most probably, just for reference I was on windows 10v.1909 before and even now, the update was minor a fix perhaps.
I still don't know what caused the error 31, & which particular update fixed the conflict, was it dell support software which was continuously on or windows, but I'm pretty sure its fixed.
Thanks to all those who helped for your time & support.